# Why does mq_open creates queeue node with a different permission than specified?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, message-queue, file-permissions

I am on an IMX chip running a distro with yocto linux.
In one of my apps, I am calling mq_open with flags `O_CREAT | O_RDWR` and mode as
`S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR`

However, the actual device node is having permissions:

```
root@NEW-Board:~# ls -l /dev/mqueue/my-ipc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 80 Nov 22 12:34 my-ipc
```

I would have expected the permissions to be `-rw-rw-rw-`. Whats happening here?

Comment: From the documentation: **The permissions settings are masked against the
       process umask.**

Comment: Just like when you create a file.

Comment: So umask applies for message queues. What about shared memory?

Comment: No, it doesn't apply to shared memory. From `umask(2)`: **The umask does not affect the permissions assigned to
       System V IPC objects created by the process (using msgget(2),
       semget(2), shmget(2)).**

Comment: I used `fmode =  umask(S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO); ` before mq_open and `umask(fmode)` after mq_open. It removed all permissions to `----------`.

Comment: `umask` is the list of permissions to *remove*. If you want the permissions to be exactly what you specified in `mq_open()`, use `umask(0)`

Comment: That interesting. So thats why `~(S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)` gave me `-rw-rw-rw-`

Comment: The man page is confusing when it says `umask() sets the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to mask & 0777` and later on goes on to say `Specifically, permissions in the umask are turned off from the mode argument to open(2) and mkdir(2)`

Comment: That's what I said. removed == turned off.

Comment: How about putting an answer so that I can check it as valid answer ?